# Error in my Java code referring to my XML button

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

When i try to link my Java to my XML, the computer doesn't seem to pick up my XML id of my buttons here is the java code:

```
package com.android.simple;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int counter;
Button add;
Button sub;
TextView display;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.bAdd);
}
}
```

XML code, as you can see, the button's id is saved as bAdd and so it is  called in the java code as well:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

     <Button
         android:layout_width="200dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tvDisplay"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="149dp"
         android:text="Subtract one" 
         android:id="@+id/bSub"
         />

     <Button
         android:layout_width="200dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bSub"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bSub"
         android:layout_marginBottom="67dp"
         android:text="Add one" 
         android:id="@+id/bAdd"
         />

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         android:layout_height="20dp"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.00"
         android:text="Your total is 0 " 
         android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is the exception/stack trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.bAdd);
```

to

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
 add = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.bAdd);
```

to this

```
 add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
```